# Knuth-Morris-Pratt over a source of indeterminate length

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, search

Please review my generic implementation of the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). Its modified to search a source of indeterminate length in a memory efficient fashion.

```
namespace Code
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>
    /// A generic implementation of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm that searches,
    /// in a memory efficient way, over a given <see cref="IEnumerator"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static class KMP
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether the Enumerator contains the specified pattern.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of an item.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">
        ///     The source, the <see cref="IEnumerator"/> must yield 
        ///     objects of <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pattern">The pattern.</param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">The equality comparer.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///   <c>true</c> if the source contains the specified pattern;
        ///   otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">pattern</exception>
        public static bool Contains<T>(
                this IEnumerator source,
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = null)
        {
            if (pattern == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
            }

            equalityComparer = equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

            return SearchImplementation(pattern, source, equalityComparer).Any();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies indices of a pattern string in source.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of an item.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="patternString">The pattern string.</param>
        /// <param name="source">
        ///     The source, the <see cref="IEnumerator"/> must yield
        ///     objects of <typeparamref name="T"/>.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">The equality comparer.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     A sequence of indices where the pattern can be found
        ///     in the source.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        ///     patternSequence - The pattern must contain 1 or more elements.
        /// </exception>
        private static IEnumerable<long> SearchImplementation<T>(
            IEnumerable<T> patternString,
            IEnumerator source,
            IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
        {
            // Pre-process the pattern
            var preResult = GetSlide(patternString, equalityComparer);
            var pattern = preResult.Pattern;
            var slide = preResult.Slide;
            var patternLength = pattern.Count;

            if (pattern.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    nameof(patternString),
                    "The pattern must contain 1 or more elements.");
            }

            var buffer = new Dictionary<long, T>(patternLength);
            var more = true;

            long i = 0; // index for source
            int j = 0; // index for pattern

            while (more)
            {
                more = FillBuffer(
                        buffer,
                        source, 
                        i,
                        patternLength,
                        out T t);

                if (equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[j], t))
                {
                    j++;
                    i++;
                }

                more = FillBuffer(
                        buffer,
                        source,
                        i,
                        patternLength,
                        out t);

                if (j == patternLength)
                {
                    yield return i - j;
                    j = slide[j - 1];
                }
                else if (more && !equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[j], t))
                {
                    if (j != 0)
                    {
                        j = slide[j - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fills the buffer.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        ///     The buffer is used so that it is not necessary to hold the
        ///     entire source in memory.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of an item.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="buffer">The buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="s">The source enumerator.</param>
        /// <param name="i">The current index.</param>
        /// <param name="patternLength">Length of the pattern.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The value retrieved from the source.</param>
        /// <returns>
        ///     <c>true</c> if there is potentially more data to process; 
        ///     otherwise <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool FillBuffer<T>(
            IDictionary<long, T> buffer,
            IEnumerator s,
            long i,
            int patternLength,
            out T value)
        {
            bool more = true;
            if (!buffer.TryGetValue(i, out value))
            {
                more = s.MoveNext();
                if (more)
                {
                    value = (T)s.Current;
                    buffer.Remove(i - patternLength);
                    buffer.Add(i, value);
                }
            }

            return more;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the offset array which acts as a slide rule for the KMP algorithm.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">The type of an item.</typeparam>
        /// <param name="pattern">The pattern.</param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">The equality comparer.</param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of the offsets and the enumerated pattern.</returns>
        private static (IReadOnlyList<int> Slide, IReadOnlyList<T> Pattern) GetSlide<T>(
                IEnumerable<T> pattern, 
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
        {
            var patternList = pattern.ToList();
            var slide = new int[patternList.Count];

            int length = 0;
            int i = 1;

            while (i < patternList.Count)
            {
                if (equalityComparer.Equals(patternList[i], patternList[length]))
                {
                    length++;
                    slide[i] = length;
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (length != 0)
                    {
                        length = slide[length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        slide[i] = length;
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return (slide, patternList);
        }
    }
}
```

I've used the non-generic `IEnumerator` for representing the source as it allows a wider breadth of enumerators to represent data, including the [`TextElementEnumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2). This enables the generic implementation to be used trivially to search Unicode strings with different normalizations, e.g.

```
namespace Code
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var testData = new List<(string Source, string Pattern)>
                {
                    (string.Empty, "x"),
                    ("y", "x"),
                    ("x", "x"),
                    ("yx", "x"),
                    ("xy", "x"),
                    ("aababccba", "abc"),
                    ("1x2x3x4", "x"),
                    ("x1x2x3x4x", "x"),
                    ("1aababcabcd2aababcabcd3aababcabcd4", "aababcabcd"),
                    ("ssstring", "sstring")
                };

            foreach(var d in testData)
            {
                var contains = Ext.Contains(d.Source, d.Pattern);
                Console.WriteLine(
                 $"Source:\"{d.Source}\", Pattern:\"{d.Pattern}\", Contains:{contains}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static bool Contains(
            this string source,
            string value,
            CultureInfo culture = null,
            StringComparer comparer = null)
        {
            comparer = comparer ?? StringComparer.Ordinal;

            var sourceEnumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(source);
            var sequenceEnumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);

            var pattern = new List<string>();
            while (sequenceEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                pattern.Add((string)sequenceEnumerator.Current);
            }

            return sourceEnumerator.Contains(pattern, comparer);
        }
    }
}
```

---

This question was [improved following the answer here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211683/improved-knuth-morris-pratt-over-a-source-of-indeterminate-length).

Comment: You may want to fix that typo in `KMP.Contains` (`pattern != null`) before an answer comes in.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet, sorry being really dense, I do see what you mean!!!

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an `IEnumerator` as first argument is quite unexpected, and makes this method more cumbersome to use than it needs to be. I'd stick to `IEnumerable<T>`.

It looks like `StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator` was an important motivation for this decision, but that's an old method that predates the introduction of generics. Why not write a wrapper method for that instead, one that returns `IEnumerable<string>`?

---

A few other points:

- You can use tuple deconstruction when calling `Slide`: `var (slide, pattern) = GetSlide(patternString, equalityComparer);`.
- It's good to see documentation, but some of it isn't very useful. If parameter documentation is just a repetition of the (already properly descriptive) parameter name then I would leave it out.
- I'd rename `i` to `sourceIndex` and `j` to `patternIndex`. Those comments already indicate that those names aren't sufficiently descriptive.
- The `culture` parameter in `Ext.Contains` is not used.
- `TextElementEnumerator` has a `GetTextElement` method, which gives you `Current` as a `string`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm looking at this block of code

```
while (more)
{
    more = FillBuffer(buffer, source, i, patternLength, out T t);

    if (equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[j], t))
    {
        j++;
        i++;
    }

    more = FillBuffer(buffer, source, i, patternLength, out T t);

    ...
}
```

> I'm not convinced that it is correct...
>   Based how I read it, in the scenario that your `if` statement is `false`, then `FillBuffer` will **return the same result**, therefore it is a redundant call.

I would consider changing the code to something like this...

```
while (more)
{
    more = FillBuffer(buffer, source, i, patternLength, out T t);

    if (equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[j], t))
    {
        j++;
        i++;

        // now inside the if statement
        more = FillBuffer(buffer, source, i, patternLength, out T t);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: this makes logical sense to me and, it works in my testing.

Comment: I've updated my question to incorporate these changes. In lieu of a more substantial update in the near future, I'll mark this as the answer.