# Improved Knuth-Morris-Pratt over a source of indeterminate length

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, search

Following the [successful review of my previous implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/211622/knuth-morris-pratt-over-a-source-of-indeterminate-length).

Please review my new, generic implementation of the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). Its modified to search a source of indeterminate length in a memory efficient fashion.

```
namespace Code
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;

    /// <summary>
    /// A generic implementation of the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm that searches,
    /// in a memory efficient way, over a given <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public static class KMP
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Determines whether a sequence contains the search string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">
        /// A sequence of elements
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="pattern">The search string.</param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">
        /// Determines whether the sequence contains a specified element.
        /// If <c>null</c>
        /// <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}.Default"/> will be used.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <c>true</c> if the source contains the specified pattern;
        /// otherwise, <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">pattern</exception>
        public static bool Contains<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source,
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = null)
        {
            if (pattern == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
            }

            equalityComparer = equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

            return SearchImplementation(source, pattern, equalityComparer).Any();
        }

        public static IEnumerable<long> IndicesOf<T>(
                this IEnumerable<T> source,
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer = null)
        {
            if (pattern == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pattern));
            }

            equalityComparer = equalityComparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

            return SearchImplementation(source, pattern, equalityComparer);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies indices of a pattern string in a given sequence.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="source">
        /// The sequence to search.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="patternString">
        /// The string to find in the sequence.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">
        /// Determines whether the sequence contains a specified element.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>
        /// A sequence of indices where the pattern can be found
        /// in the source.
        /// </returns>
        /// <exception cref="ArgumentOutOfRangeException">
        /// patternSequence - The pattern must contain 1 or more elements.
        /// </exception>
        private static IEnumerable<long> SearchImplementation<T>(
            IEnumerable<T> source,
            IEnumerable<T> patternString,
            IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
        {
            // Pre-process the pattern
            (var slide, var pattern) = GetSlide(patternString, equalityComparer);
            var patternLength = pattern.Count;

            if (patternLength == 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
                    nameof(patternString),
                    "The pattern must contain 1 or more elements.");
            }

            var buffer = new Dictionary<long, T>(patternLength);
            var more = true;

            long sourceIndex = 0; // index for source
            int patternIndex = 0; // index for pattern

            using(var sourceEnumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
            while (more)
            {
                more = FillBuffer(
                        buffer,
                        sourceEnumerator,
                        sourceIndex,
                        patternLength,
                        out T t);

                if (equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[patternIndex], t))
                {
                    patternIndex++;
                    sourceIndex++;

                    more = FillBuffer(
                        buffer,
                        sourceEnumerator,
                        sourceIndex,
                        patternLength,
                        out t);
                }

                if (patternIndex == patternLength)
                {
                    yield return sourceIndex - patternIndex;
                    patternIndex = slide[patternIndex - 1];
                }
                else if (more && !equalityComparer.Equals(pattern[patternIndex], t))
                {
                    if (patternIndex != 0)
                    {
                        patternIndex = slide[patternIndex - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sourceIndex = sourceIndex + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Services the buffer and retrieves the value.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// The buffer is used so that it is not necessary to hold the
        /// entire source in memory.
        /// </remarks>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="buffer">The buffer.</param>
        /// <param name="source">The source enumerator.</param>
        /// <param name="sourceIndex">The element index to retrieve.</param>
        /// <param name="patternLength">Length of the search string.</param>
        /// <param name="value">The element value retrieved from the source.</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// <c>true</c> if there is potentially more data to process;
        /// otherwise <c>false</c>.
        /// </returns>
        private static bool FillBuffer<T>(
            IDictionary<long, T> buffer,
            IEnumerator<T> source,
            long sourceIndex,
            int patternLength,
            out T value)
        {
            bool more = true;
            if (!buffer.TryGetValue(sourceIndex, out value))
            {
                more = source.MoveNext();
                if (more)
                {
                    value = source.Current;
                    buffer.Remove(sourceIndex - patternLength);
                    buffer.Add(sourceIndex, value);
                }
            }

            return more;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the offset array which acts as a slide rule for the KMP algorithm.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">
        /// The type of elements of <paramref name="source"/>.
        /// </typeparam>
        /// <param name="pattern">The search string.</param>
        /// <param name="equalityComparer">
        /// Determines whether the sequence contains a specified element.
        /// If <c>null</c>
        /// <see cref="EqualityComparer{T}.Default"/> will be used.
        /// </param>
        /// <returns>A tuple of the offsets and the enumerated pattern.</returns>
        private static (IReadOnlyList<int> Slide, IReadOnlyList<T> Pattern) GetSlide<T>(
                IEnumerable<T> pattern,
                IEqualityComparer<T> equalityComparer)
        {
            var patternList = pattern.ToList();
            var slide = new int[patternList.Count];

            int length = 0;
            int patternIndex = 1;

            while (patternIndex < patternList.Count)
            {
                if (equalityComparer.Equals(
                        patternList[patternIndex],
                        patternList[length]))
                {
                    length++;
                    slide[patternIndex] = length;
                    patternIndex++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (length != 0)
                    {
                        length = slide[length - 1];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        slide[patternIndex] = length;
                        patternIndex++;
                    }
                }
            }

            return (slide, patternList);
        }
    }
}
```

Below is an example of how this algorithm could be used. Here [`TextElementEnumerator`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.textelementenumerator?view=netframework-4.7.2) is used with the generic implementation to trivially search Unicode strings with different Unicode Normalizations.

```
namespace Code
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Linq;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var decomposed = "ṩ".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);
            var composed = "ṩ".Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormKC);

            var testData = new List<(string Source, string Pattern)>
                {
                    (string.Empty, composed),
                    ($"y", composed),
                    ($"{decomposed}", composed),
                    ($"y{decomposed}", composed),
                    ($"{decomposed}y", composed),
                    ($"a{composed}{decomposed}{composed}b",
                                       $"{composed}{decomposed}{composed}"),
                    ($"aabab{decomposed}bcc", $"ab{composed}"),
                };

            foreach (var d in testData)
            {
                var contains = Ext.Contains(
                                d.Source,
                                d.Pattern,
                                StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
                Console.WriteLine(
          $"Source:\"{d.Source}\", Pattern:\"{d.Pattern}\", Contains:({contains})");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class Ext
    {
        public static bool Contains(
            this string source,
            string value,
            StringComparer comparer = null)
        {
            comparer = comparer ?? StringComparer.Ordinal;

            return GetTextElements(source).Contains(GetTextElements(value), comparer);
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> GetTextElements(string source)
        {
            var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(source);
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                yield return enumerator.GetTextElement();
            }
        }
    }
}
```